# Django: URL Reverse for '/job/job_view/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I just started out trying to user `django` `reverse` for URL lookups and ran into this issue. Everything I see looks like it should work. I'm passing it the `view` def to render the page, as well as the `slug` and `id` so it renders the correct page. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone has any pointers on what could be causing this error I would most appreciate it.

The error is this:

```
Reverse for '/job/job_view/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'testing-form-proficiencies', 'jobid': u'59'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here's the code:

***views.py***

```
# Watch a Job
def job_watch(request, jobid):

    job = Jobs.objects.get(id=jobid)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        JobsWatch.objects.create(job_id=jobid, user_id=request.user.id, watching=1)
        render_to_response(reverse('/job/job_view/', args=(), kwargs={'jobid': jobid, 'slug': job.slug}))

# View a single Job
def job_view(request, jobid, slug):

    companyId = Jobs.objects.get(id=jobid).user_id

    # Get associated Job Proficiencies IDs attached to a Job
    profid = JobProficiencies_Proficiencies.objects.filter(job_id=jobid).select_related('job_proficiencies_id')
    # Get the Proficiency values attached to the job
    proficiencies = JobProficiencies.objects.filter(id__in=profid).select_related('job_proficiency', 'proficiency_required', 'comfort_level')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['job'] = get_object_or_404(Jobs, id=jobid, slug=slug)
    args['company'] = get_object_or_404(User, id=companyId)
    args['proficiencies'] = proficiencies

    return render_to_response('job/view.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/j(?P<jobid>\d+)$', 'job.views.job_view', name="view_job"),
    url(r'^all/$', 'job.views.all_jobs', name="view_jobs"),
    url(r'^create/$', 'job.views.create', name="create_job"),
    url(r'^edit/j(?P<jobid>\d+)/$', 'job.views.edit', name="edit_job"),
    url(r'^watch/j(?P<jobid>\d+)/$', 'job.views.job_watch', name='job_watch'),
)
```

Appreciate anyone taking the time to view this question. Cheers.

Comment: Consider changing the order of your urls so that `^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/j(?P<jobid>\d+)$` appears last, otherwise you might experience unexpected results in the future, i.e. it will match `watch/j(?P<jobid>\d+)$`. You've got the trailing forward slash there, but it's the only thing that saves you from this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up kroolik!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three issues with the `job_watch` view:

1. First argument to the `reverse()` function need to be a proper
   urlpattern name or a view import path. Change `/job/job_view/` in
   the actual name of the urlpattern:

   ```
   reverse('view_job', kwargs={'jobid': jobid, 'slug': job.slug})
   ```
2. What do you want to achieve by passing the URL returned by
   `reverse()` to `render_to_response()`? Whatever it is this approach
   won't work. If you want to redirect user to the url use
   [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

   ```
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_job', kwargs={'jobid': jobid, 'slug': job.slug}))
   ```

   You can use [Django's redirect shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to make this code
   shorter:

   ```
   return redirect('view_job', jobid=jobid, slug=job.slug)
   ```
3. Right now your view doesn't return anything. Never. I already corrected part of this in the code above, but the code is invoked only if the method is POST. You need to still return *something* if the method is not POST, or use the [`require_POST()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) decorator to indicate that the request *have to be* POST.

Final code:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@require_POST
def job_watch(request, jobid):
    job = Jobs.objects.get(id=jobid)
    JobsWatch.objects.create(job_id=jobid, user_id=request.user.id, watching=1)
    return redirect('view_job', jobid=jobid, slug=job.slug)
```

Comment: `redirect` from `django.shortcuts` could also come in handy.

Comment: Hello Ludwik,

Changing my `reverse` URL to: 
`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_job', kwargs={'jobid': jobid, 'slug': job.slug}))`
Seems to match the URL pattern now. But now I receive the error:
`The view job.views.job_watch didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

The `render_to_response` was me fiddling around trying to get this issue resolved. You're absolutely right that I want to use `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: I already updated my post in the meantime. Look at the expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Ludwik! What you stated worked, and I see what I was doing wrong. Appreciate the very in depth answer so quickly!